# Erronious redirect URL after using cURL

Tags: php, redirect, curl

I have php code copied from postman, when this code is executed from my site, I get an error, the redirect url I get back from cURL contains escape characters. How can I tell cURL to leave the redirect string untouched?

The message I get is:
cURL Error: Bad URL{"redirect":"http: \ / \ / ...  (<- added spaces to make visible, aren't really there in the error message, url continues after this, every slash is proceeded by a backslash)

My code is:

```
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => "https:////portal.reeleezee.nl//api//v1//{removed adminid}//salesinvoices//36bed12c-4204-4e56-ba23-0da56ca9dccd",
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => @'{"Date": "2017-09-21T00:00:00", "Header": "Subject: Sales invoice to H n L Company on purchase of flash drives", "Status": 1, "DocumentType": 10,   "Origin": 2,   "Type": 1, "DocumentLineList": [ { "id":"4c61e490-cbef-431a-be74-0fc2ab581e4f", "Sequence": 2, "Quantity": 2, "Price": 135, "Description": "Allium Gladiator His Excellence", "InvoiceLineType": 4, "DiscountAmount": null,  "DiscountPercentage": null,  "TaxRate": { "id": "1e44993a-15f6-419f-87e5-3e31ac3d9383" }    }  ],    "Entity":  { "id": "d7ae1602-4649-48dc-a75a-a9eafea7938f",    }}',
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "accept: application/json",
            "accept-language: en",
            "authorization: Basic {removed auth}",
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "content-type: application/json",
            "postman-token: {removed}",
            "prefer: return=representation"
          ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
          echo "cURL Error BAH #:" . $err;
        } else {
          echo $response;
        }
```

Comment: get rid of your double slashing, you're not escaping anything there `\` is

Comment: Scuzzy, my excuses, I edited the question to make clear what my real problem is. The double slashing is there because curl does change this url as well. If I leave the single slashing there, I get an error message that this is an incorrect url.

Comment: four slashes after `https:` is not a legal URL, not even to curl.

Comment: Okay, tried it with 'CURLOPT_URL => "https :/ /portal.reeleezee.nl/api/v1/{removed}/salesinvoices/36bed12c-4204-4e56-ba23-0da56ca9dccd",'. This results in "Internal Server Error"

Comment: My problem is not in this line, my problem is that I get a redirect url with backslashes added before every slash. How can I change this behaviour, or how can I set the redirect URL myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message did not come from the cURL statement. If I have an 'echo' statement somewhere in my function, the redirect url will be escaped...

Don't know how or why, but my problem is solved (echo statement is only there for errors)

Answer (score 0):

The url you passing to api must be urlencoded use php urlencode() function. it will resolve your problem;